# Azure SQL - Automatic Tuning with Geo-replication - Server in unspecified state and query store has reached its capacity limit

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, sql-query-store

I have a primary db and a secondary geo-replicated db.
On the primary, the server atuomatic tuning is turned on.

On the replica when I try to do the same I encounter the following issues.

> The database is inheriting settings from the server, but the server is
>   in the unspecified state. Please specify the automatic tuning state on
>   the server.

And

> Automated recommendation management is disabled because Query Store
>   has reached its capacity limit and is not collecting new data. Learn
>   more about the retention policies to maintain Query Store so new data
>   can be collected.

However, on the server, tuning options are `on` so I don't understand that "unspecified state". Moreover, why I look at the Query Store set up in both databases properties in SSMS they are exactly the same with 9MB of space available out of 10MB.

Note: both databases are setup on the 5 DTUs basic pricing plan.

UPDATE

While the primary db Query store Operation Mode is Read Write, the replica is Read Only. It seems I cannot change it (I couldn't from the properties dialog of the db in SSMS).

Fair enough but how can the same query be 10 times faster on primary than on replica. Aren't optimizations copied accross?

UPDATE 2

Actually Query Store are viewable on SSMS and I can see that they are identical in both db. I think the difference in response times that I observe is not related.

UPDATE 3

I marked [@vCillusion](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1688718/vcillusion)'s post as the answer as he/she deserves credits. However, it's too detailed with regards to the actual issue.

My replica is read-only and as such cannot be auto-tuned as this would require writing in the query store. Azure not being able to collect any data into the read only query store led to a misleading (and wrong) error message about the query store reaching its capacity.

Comment: Query Store automatically changes the operation mode to read-only and stops collecting new data, which means that your performance analysis is no longer accurate. For the same reason, I am not sure if we can rely on its data.

Comment: The difference in the response times might be related to the `DATA_FLUSH_INTERVAL_SECONDS`. Query Store can lose runtime data in events of session termination or client application restart.

Comment: Can we also compare the query plan to see what is causing the difference in the response times?

Comment: How can I see the query plan of a request made via a web api with entity framework? No sql or stored proc here.

Comment: As of now, there is no filtering mechanism in Query Store to identify queries executed by Entity Framework. You can enable Query Store on all the databases and monitor query data and filter out by SQL text. You can try Extended Events or Events Trace for full control. Query Store is still evolving. https://stackoverflow.com/q/49669544/1688718

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We get this message only when the Query Store is in read-only mode. Double check your query store configuration.
According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt604821.aspx), you might need to consider below:

1. To recover Query Store try explicitly setting the read-write mode and recheck actual state.

   ```
   ALTER DATABASE [QueryStoreDB]   
   SET QUERY_STORE (OPERATION_MODE = READ_WRITE);    
   GO  

   SELECT actual_state_desc, desired_state_desc, current_storage_size_mb,   
   max_storage_size_mb, readonly_reason, interval_length_minutes,   
   stale_query_threshold_days, size_based_cleanup_mode_desc,   
   query_capture_mode_desc  
   FROM sys.database_query_store_options;
   ```
2. If the problem persists, it indicates corruption of the Query Store data and continues on the disk. We can recover Query Store by executing `sp_query_store_consistency_check` stored procedure within the affected database.
3. If that did not help, you could try to clear Query Store before requesting read-write mode.

   ```
   ALTER DATABASE [QueryStoreDB]   
   SET QUERY_STORE CLEAR;  
   GO  

   ALTER DATABASE [QueryStoreDB]   
   SET QUERY_STORE (OPERATION_MODE = READ_WRITE);    
   GO  

   SELECT actual_state_desc, desired_state_desc, current_storage_size_mb,   
       max_storage_size_mb, readonly_reason, interval_length_minutes,   
       stale_query_threshold_days, size_based_cleanup_mode_desc,   
       query_capture_mode_desc  
   FROM sys.database_query_store_options;
   ```

> If you checked it and it's in read-write mode, then we might be dealing with some bug here. Please provide feedback to Microsoft on this.

**Additional points of limitation in query store:**

Also, note Query Store feature is introduced to monitor performance and is still evolving. There are certain known limitations around it.

> As of now, it does not work on Read-Only databases (Including read-only AG replicas). Since readable secondary Replicas are read-only,
>   the query store on those secondary replicas is also read-only. This
>   means runtime statistics for queries executed on those replicas are
>   not recorded into the query store.

1. Check database is not Read-Only.
2. Query store didn't work for system databases like master or tempdb
3. Check if Primary filegroup have enough memory since the Data is stored only in Primary filegroup

Comment: My db is indeed read-only as it is a replica. But why isn't the query store data of the primary db copied to replicas? The exact same query on primary takes 1.5s while it takes 9.5s on replica. Surely auto tuning added some index. Why aren't they replicated?

Answer (score 1):

The supported scenario is that Automatic tuning needs to be enabled on the primary only. Index automatically created on the primary will be automatically replicated to the secondary. This process takes the usual sync up time between the primary and the secondary. At this time it is not possible to have secondary read only replica tuned differently for performance than the primary. The query store error message is due to its read-only state as note above, and should be disregarded. The performance issue to your secondary replica most likely needs to be explored through some other reasons.